# Efficient CoreData fetches using subqueries

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, subquery, relationship

I've got a iOS Core Data performance problem.

Let's assume that we have 2 classes: "Class_A" and "Class_B". Both of them have their own ids and one-to-one relations between each other.

[image: classes]

Now let's assume that I'm downloading data from the web that allows me to create these classes (data contains id's of Classes A and B, and informations about their relations). For example:

- "There will be instance of Class_A with id=1"
- "There will be instance of Class_A with id=2"
- "There will be instance of Class_A with id=3"
- "There will be instance of Class_B with id=10"
- "There will be instance of Class_B with id=11"
- "There will be instance of Class_B with id=12"
- "Class_A with id=1 will be connected with Class_B with id = 12"
- "Class_A with id=2 will be connected with Class_B with id = 11"
- "Class_A with id=3 will be connected with Class_B with id = 10"

Because all these informations can be obtained in random order (for example information about connections between X and Y classes can be downloaded before info about existance of classes X and Y), I've used another kind of entity: Relationship.

Relationship contains of 2 fields: class_A_id and class_b_id

[image: relationship]

Every time I recieve data about relationship between ClassA and ClassB, I create instance of Relationship entity with according properties values.

Than every certain period of time I'm iterating over all instances of "Relationship" entities, and trying to create proper relations like this:

1. Fetch all instances of "Relationship" entity
2. For every fetched Relationship fetch instance of ClassA and ClassB according to "class_A_id" and "class_B_id" ids stored in Relationsip
3. If both - instance of ClassA and ClassB exists - create relationship beetween them.
4. Remove instance Relationship from the CoreData

After implementing this algorithm I've figured out it works well when using with rather low quantities of objects in Core Data. 
The problem is that i'm storing thousands of "relationship" entities (informations about them are downloaded first) while informations about existance of "ClassA" and "ClassB" are downloaded less frequently.

The result is that every time I'm trying to create relationships using "Relationship" entities I'm fetching thousands of objects that contains id's of classes that don't exists!

So my solution to this problem is to enhance first step of proposed algorithm:

Instead of fetching all relationships in the CoreData, fetch only these that contains id's of Classes that exists in the system.

In SQL it would probably looks something like this:

```
SELECT * from 'Relationship' where
    (SELECT * from 'ClassA' where id == class_A_id).count == 1
  AND
    (SELECT * from 'ClassB' where id == class_B_id).count == 1
```

My question is - how to achieve query like this in CoreData? Use subqueries there? Is yes - how? :)

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, could you throw away your Relationship entity and instead just create instances of ClassA and ClassB and link them together via their relationship?  You could add an attribute to these entities to indicate that it is placeholder instead of a fully populated entity?

Comment: You can also mimic you SQL way: When you receive class X and class Y, you can check against Relationship.  And when you receive relationship data, you can check against Class_A and Class_B.  But AE's suggestion probably works out better.

Comment: Ok, so as you've probably guessed model in my real application is a little bit more complicated - classes "ClassA" and "ClassB" have more properties than "id", and data needed to fill those properties don't come in web responses that contains only relationships between them.

I can't create "fake" entities of these classed (with only "id" field populated) because of structure of my app - I need to create them only then when I have full info about them.

I've simplified my problem in order to ask my question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, if you don't want to modify too much your model, you have two options:

- First option: modify the request process to only ask for relationship about entities you already have, this can be done easily if you have not so much entities of type A,B. Otherwise implement some sort of 'delta', this will avoid to have thousands of relationship you don't need (unless you need it for other purpose).
- Second option: when you download items, I suppose it is a background process, in this case I would do the check immediately within there, and not batch from time to time. For example, you are downloading relationship, check if you already have A or B and mark the relationship table as complete or incomplete (maybe adding two attributes aExists bExists). As soon as entity A came in, go and mark all those entity in relationship as aExists, the same goes for B coming in, this is a normal fetch request where class_A_id exists. Then the batch can easily scan and get only those entities marked as complete, and create relationship. You have to implement a little logic, but in my opinion things would get faster.

New relationship would be:

```
Relationships {
  class_A_id,
  class_B_id,
  classAexists BOOL,
  classBexists BOOL,
  batchRelationshipCreated BOOL,
}
```

Well you can implement both options anyway :-)